# Take data in $scope of angularjs while taking data from django

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I am calling the class based view

```
class CurrentUser(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        for user in User.objects.all()
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                fullname = user.get_full_name()
                return Response(fullname)
```

from the url

```
url(r'^currentuser$', views.CurrentUser.as_view(), name='current-user'
```

I am getting current username. But I want to take that data into $scope of angularjs controller in following way.. Please.. Any help would be appreciated..

```
controllersModule.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $http, User , Product ,Process ,Ingredient) {

        $scope.$on('event:login-confirmed', function() {
            $scope.users = User.query();
            $scope.products = Product.query();
            $scope.processes = Process.query();
            $scope.ingredients = Ingredient.query();
            // $scope.currentUser = get;
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `User` is a service? If you are using the $http or Restangular you probably get a promise back. So you will end up with a promise in the scope, which is probably not what you want.

So you probably want this:

```
$scope.$on('event:login-confirmed', function() {
            User.query().then(function(data) { $scope.users = data;});
            ...
        });
```